# Проверить наличие элемента в массиве

Tags: javascript

Есть массив

```
var array = {};
```

в него добавляю подмассив

```
array[1] = array{k1: v1, k2: v2}
```

при повторном добавлении данных в массив, как мне проверить есть ли уже в этом массиве элемент 1 с подмассивом, дабы избежать повторного добавления.

Comment: это не массив `{}` это объект

Comment: простите, тогда как правильно мне объявить массив, добавить в него сложенный и потом проверять есть ли в основном массиве этот вложенный ??

Comment: Формально, в js вообще нет массивов. `typeof []` вам выдаст `object` :D

Comment: объект использовать вполне логично, нужно только придумать каждому подмассиву уникальный ключ и проверять его наличие в объекте

Comment: можно практический пример?

Comment: Вы хотите по значению массива проверять или есть возможность создать уникальные идентификаторы массивов? по значениям проверять дольше и сложнее

Comment: мне вообще не принципиально можно и уникальные ид создать, и наверно так даже лучше будет.но тогда можно полный пример от создания уникального ид до проверки на его наличие

Comment: а не могли бы Вы еще написать что это за данные и зачем их складывать в один объект?

Comment: а какой размер подмассивов будет? и что там хранится?

Comment: это получается объект (массив) с данными о пользователях. где уникальный ид это ид пользователя а логин и ссылка на аватар это данные подмассива поторые добавляются в этот объект(массив). я делаю это чтоб не делать постоянно запросы в базу

Comment: размер массива такой как написан в изначальном вопросе, массив с подмассивом где только 2 элемента

Comment: Вот Вы сделали необходимые уточнения и сразу нашелся желающий написать ответ =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> это получается объект (массив) с данными о пользователях. где уникальный ид это ид пользователя а логин и ссылка на аватар это данные подмассива поторые добавляются в этот объект(массив).

Ну если `id` у пользователя уникальный, то лучше хранить все в объекте. Ключ - `id`, а значение, это уже объект с данными

Тогда проверка на наличие станет вообще тривиальной
Можно написать даже целый класс для пользователя ( любой сущности )

```js
class Users {
  data_ = {}

  add(user) {
    // Если пользователя нет
    if(!this.data_[user.id]) {
      this.data_[user.id] = user;
    }
  }
  
  delete(id) {
    return delete this.data_[id];
  }
  
  // Обновить данные пользователя, который уже есть
  update(user) {
    if (this.data_[user.id]) {
      this.data_[user.id] = user;
    }
  }
  
  // Получить список пользователей
  getAll() {
    return Object.values(this.data_);
  }
}

const user1 = {login: 'login', id: '1', avatar: 'link'};
const user2 = {login: 'login', id: '2', avatar: 'link'};
const user3 = {login: 'login', id: '3', avatar: 'link'};
const usersDB = new Users();
usersDB.add(user1);
usersDB.add(user2);
usersDB.add(user3);
usersDB.add(user1); // здесь ничего не произойдет
console.log('Get all users');
console.log(usersDB.getAll());

console.log('Update user');
usersDB.update({login: 'login1', id: '1', avatar: 'link1'});
console.log(usersDB.getAll());

console.log('Delete user');
usersDB.delete(2);
console.log(usersDB.getAll());
```